# How to build this graph in Python?

Tags: python, graph, tree

I am practicing Python want to create a graph in python with a starting node and some requirements for the children. The value of each node will be 3 digits (e.g. 320, 110), and I want to generate the children in the following order:

- 1 is subtracted from the first digit
- 1 is added to the first digit
- 1 is subtracted from the second digit
- 1 is added to the second digit
- 1 is subtracted from the third digit
- 1 is added to the third digit

The input of the start node and goal node is from a text file, and they might have a third line with a list of forbidden numbers which are numbers that the search algorithm cannot visit.

Constraints:

- You cannot add to the digit 9 or subtract from the digit 0;
- You cannot make a move that transforms the current number into one of 
  the forbidden numbers;
- You cannot change the same digit twice in two successive moves.

Note that since the numbers have 3 digits, at the beginning there are at most 6 possible moves from starting node.
After the first move, the branching factor is at most 4, due to the constraints on the moves and especially due to constraint 3.

I have already implemented a Node class for my graph, but I am having problems with actually building the graph.

This is what I have done with the Node class:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.children = []
        self.parent = []

    def add_child(self, obj):
        self.children.append(obj)

    def add_parent(self, obj):
        self.parent.append(obj)

root = Node(320)

def get_root():
    print(root.data)

# some things I've tried
# p = Node(root.data-100)
# p.add_parent(root.data)
# root.add_child(p.data)
# set_root(320)
get_root()
# print(root.data)
# print(root.children)
# print(p.parent)
# p = Node(root.data-100)
```

I have implemented a BFS which gives the correct path output when give a graph, but I am unable to create the actual graph to use in this BFS. Here is my BFS:

```
visited = set()

def bfs(graph_to_search, start, end):
    queue = [[start]]
    # visited = set()

    while queue:
        # Gets the first path in the queue
        path = queue.pop(0)

        # Gets the last node in the path
        vertex = path[-1]

        # Checks if we got to the end
        if vertex == end:
            return path
        # We check if the current node is already in the visited nodes 
            set in order not to recheck it
        elif vertex not in visited:
            # enumerate all adjacent nodes, construct a new path 
                    and push it into the queue
            for current_neighbour in graph_to_search.get(vertex[]):
                new_path = list(path)
                new_path.append(current_neighbour)
                queue.append(new_path)

            # Mark the vertex as visited
            visited.add(vertex)
```

Example:
With a start node: 320 and end node: 110, with no forbidden nodes, A BFS search on this graph would look like:

[image]

[image]

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: why does your tree have the ability of adding multiple parents? Kind of makes it a graph rather than a tree.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say graph. I have edited the post to reflect this.

Comment: what exactly did you encounter as an issue when you tried to build the graph?

Comment: I don't know how to go around and build the graph. Like adding the children with those requirements recursively (or not recursively), and formatting the nodes properly.

Comment: In the file, the start node and end node are also three digit representations?

Comment: When you have to do those operations, like adding 1 or subtracting 1, is it relative to the current node or in general to the whole state of the graph?

Comment: Yes, the start node and end node are also three digit representations. I'm not quite sure what you mean by the second question. So for example, if the start node is 330, and end node is 110. The graph will create the children of 320 resulting in childs (220, 420, 310, 330, and 321), then the graph creates childs for 220 resulting in childs ( 230, 210 and 221)

Comment: aha, so for each child you must execute all of those operations, and the result of each operation will be a child. What happens if one operation somewhere in the graph results in a child with the same 3-digit formation as another one that already exists in the graph?

Comment: That is fine, as long as they are not the same node. Two nodes are the same if a) they have the same 3 digits; and b) they have the same ‘child’ nodes. Also, there cannot be any cycles in the graph.

Comment: @andreihondrari I have edited the post with an example

Comment: and what is `You cannot change the same digit twice in two successive moves.` suppose to mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191260/discussion-between-andreihondrari-and-fatimahfatcakes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to create a model of the `Node` and to generate the graph, we first must make some assumptions:

- it is an undirected graph
- the distance between the nodes is of equal value or lacking importance
- the `Node`'s will require some sort of identification number
- the generation of the neighbours is relative to the current `Node`, hence the functionality should be part of the `Node` instance
- if we don't specify a limit the `Graph` could be generated infinitely, hence we must introduce the notion of `max_spread`

Hence the code for the `Node` will look like:

```
from copy import copy

def check_three_digits(value_name, digits):
    assert len(digits) == 3, "The {} should be of precise length 3. Actual: {}".format(value_name, digits)
    assert digits.isdigit(), "The {} should consist of 3 digits. Actual {}".format(value_name, digits)


class Node:

    _node_count = 0

    def __init__(self, data: str):
        check_three_digits("data param", data)
        self._id = Node._node_count
        self._data = data
        self._neighbours = []
        Node._node_count += 1

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self._id

    @property
    def data(self):
        return copy(self._data)

    @property
    def neighbours(self):
        return copy(self._neighbours)

    def add_neighbour(self, neighbour):
        self._neighbours.append(neighbour)

    def _new_neighbour(self, data):
        new_neighbour = Node(data)
        new_neighbour.add_neighbour(self)
        return new_neighbour

    def generate_neighbours(self, forbidden_nodes_digits=[]):
        first_digit = self._data[0]
        second_digit = self._data[1]
        third_digit = self._data[2]

        first_digit_num = int(first_digit)
        second_digit_num = int(second_digit)
        third_digit_num = int(third_digit)
        sub_first_digit_num = first_digit_num - 1
        add_first_digit_num = first_digit_num + 1

        sub_second_digit_num = second_digit_num - 1
        add_second_digit_num = second_digit_num + 1

        sub_third_digit_num = third_digit_num - 1
        add_third_digit_num = third_digit_num + 1

        sub_first_digit_num = first_digit_num if sub_first_digit_num < 0 else sub_first_digit_num
        add_first_digit_num = first_digit_num if add_first_digit_num > 9 else add_first_digit_num

        sub_second_digit_num = second_digit_num if sub_second_digit_num < 0 else sub_second_digit_num
        add_second_digit_num = second_digit_num if add_second_digit_num > 9 else add_second_digit_num

        sub_third_digit_num = third_digit_num if sub_third_digit_num < 0 else sub_third_digit_num
        add_third_digit_num = third_digit_num if add_third_digit_num > 9 else add_third_digit_num


        for ndigits in [
            "{}{}{}".format(str(sub_first_digit_num), second_digit, third_digit),
            "{}{}{}".format(str(add_first_digit_num), second_digit, third_digit),
            "{}{}{}".format(first_digit, str(sub_second_digit_num), third_digit),
            "{}{}{}".format(first_digit, str(add_second_digit_num), third_digit),
            "{}{}{}".format(first_digit, second_digit, str(sub_third_digit_num)),
            "{}{}{}".format(first_digit, second_digit, str(add_third_digit_num)),
        ]:
            if ndigits in forbidden_nodes_digits:
                continue

            self._neighbours.append(self._new_neighbour(ndigits))


    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Node({})".format(self._data)
```

in order to generate the graph we have:

```
def generate_nodes(node, end_node_digits, forbidden_nodes_digits, visited_nodes=None, current_spread=0, max_spread=4):
    """
    Handles the generation of the graph.

    :node: the current node to generate neighbours for
    :end_node_digits: the digits at which to stop spreading further the graph from the current spread.
    :visited_nodes: Marks the nodes for which neighbours generation happened, to avoid repetition and infinite recursion.
    :current_spread: Marks the current level at which neighbours are being generated.
    :max_spread: Defined the max spread over which the graph should no longer generate neighbours for nodes.
    """

    # initialize the kwargs with None values
    if visited_nodes is None:
        visited_nodes = []

    # mark the current node as visited
    visited_nodes.append(node.id)

    # no reason to generate further since we hit the max spread limit
    if current_spread >= max_spread:
        return

    # generate the neighbours for the current node
    node.generate_neighbours(forbidden_nodes_digits)

    # if we generated the end node, fall back, no need to generate further
    if end_node_digits in [n.data for n in node.neighbours]:
        return

    # make sure to generate neighbours for the current node's neighbours as well
    for neighbour in node.neighbours:
        if neighbour.id in visited_nodes:
            continue

        generate_nodes(
            neighbour, end_node_digits, forbidden_nodes_digits,
            visited_nodes=visited_nodes, current_spread=current_spread + 1, max_spread=max_spread
        )
```

A Breadth First Search algorithm for such a model would look like:

```
def bfs(node, end_node_digits, visited_nodes=None, path=None):
    """
    Looks for a specific digit sequence in the graph starting from a specific node.
    :node: the node to start search from.
    :end_node_digits: The digit sequence to look for.
    :visited_nodes: The nodes for which BFS was already performed. Used to avoid infinite recursion and cyclic traversal.
    :path: The search path that lead to this node.
    """

    # initialize the None kwargs
    if visited_nodes is None:
        visited_nodes = []

    if path is None:
        path = ""
    path += "({}, {}) ".format(node.id, node.data)

    # mark the current node as visited
    visited_nodes.append(node.id)

    # if we find the end node we can safely report back the match
    if node.data == end_node_digits:
        return path

    # if the current node doesn't match the end node then we look into the neighbours
    for neighbour in node.neighbours:

        # exclude the visited nodes (obviously excluding the node that generated these nodes)
        if neighbour.id in visited_nodes:
            continue

        # do a BFS in the subdivision of the graph
        result_path = bfs(neighbour, end_node_digits, visited_nodes, path)

        # if a match was found in the neighbour subdivision, report it back
        if result_path is not None:
            return result_path

    return None
```

We can exemplify the functionality of the code written by assuming as an example the `input.txt` like:

```
320
221
330 420
```

and the `__main__` block like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    # retrieve the nodes from the input file
    start_node_digits = None
    end_node_digits = None
    forbidden_nodes_digits = []

    with open("input.txt", "r") as pf:
        start_node_digits = pf.readline().strip()
        end_node_digits = pf.readline().strip()
        forbidden_nodes_digits = pf.readline().split()

    forbidden_nodes_digits = [fnode.strip() for fnode in forbidden_nodes_digits]
    print("Start node digits: {}".format(start_node_digits))
    print("End node digits: {}".format(end_node_digits))
    print("Forbidden nodes digits: {}".format(forbidden_nodes_digits))

    # validate the input nodes data
    check_three_digits("start node", start_node_digits)
    check_three_digits("end node", end_node_digits)
    for fnode_digits in forbidden_nodes_digits:
        check_three_digits("forbidden node", fnode_digits)

    # create the first node and generate the graph
    first_node = Node(start_node_digits)
    print("Generate nodes for graph....")
    max_spread = 2
    generate_nodes(first_node, end_node_digits, forbidden_nodes_digits, max_spread=max_spread)

    # poerform a BFS for a sequence of digits
    print("BFS for {}".format(end_node_digits))
    match_path = bfs(first_node, end_node_digits)
    print("BFS search result: {}".format(match_path))
```

We could also visualize the graph by using these functions:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def _draw_node(graph, node, visited_nodes=None):

    # initialize kwargs with None values
    if visited_nodes is None:
        visited_nodes = []

    # mark node as visited
    visited_nodes.append(node.id)

    for neighbour in node.neighbours:
        if neighbour.id in visited_nodes:
            continue

        graph.add_node(neighbour.id)
        graph.add_edge(node.id, neighbour.id)
        nx.set_node_attributes(graph, {neighbour.id: {'data': neighbour.data}})

        _draw_node(graph, neighbour, visited_nodes)


def draw_graph(first_node, start_node_digits, end_node_digits, forbidden_nodes_digits, fig_scale, fig_scale_exponent=1.2):
    g = nx.Graph()

    # add first node to the draw figure
    g.add_node(first_node.id)
    nx.set_node_attributes(g, {first_node.id: {'data': first_node.data}})
    _draw_node(g, first_node)

    # prepare graph drawing
    labels = nx.get_node_attributes(g, 'data')
    fig = plt.figure(frameon=False)
    INCH_FACTOR = 5  # inches
    fig_scale = fig_scale ** fig_scale_exponent
    fig.set_size_inches(fig_scale * INCH_FACTOR, fig_scale * INCH_FACTOR)

    nodes_attributes = nx.get_node_attributes(g, 'data')

    color_map = []
    for n in g:
        ndata = nodes_attributes[n]
        if ndata == start_node_digits:
            color_map.append('yellow')
        elif ndata == end_node_digits:
            color_map.append('cyan')
        elif ndata in forbidden_nodes_digits:
            # just in case something slips
            color_map.append('red')
        else:
            color_map.append("#e5e5e5")

    # actually draw the graph and save it to a PNG.
    nx.draw_networkx(
        g, with_labels=True, labels=labels, node_size=600,
        node_color=color_map,
        # node_color='#e5e5e5',
        font_weight='bold', font_size="10",
        pos=nx.drawing.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout(g)
    )
    plt.savefig("graph.png", dpi=100)
```

which can be called in the `__main__` block like:

```
print("Draw graph...")
draw_graph(first_node, start_node_digits, end_node_digits, forbidden_nodes_digits, fig_scale=max_spread, fig_scale_exponent=1)
```

The graph looks like:

[image: graph]

For which the BFS result will be something like: `(0, 320) (1, 220) (10, 221)`

Now I'm not sure if this is entirely according to spec, but this should be a good starting point. There are also multiple ways to implement a graph, some people use lists of vertices and edges.

For `networkx`'s `graphviz` you will need to install via pip the `pygraphviz` package, and if you're on linux, you might need to do `sudo apt-get install graphviz libgraphviz-dev pkg-config`

Comment: @FatimahFatCakes did this help you out?